# Python function wont exit or direct to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

working on my python assessment and i cant get my function to do anything apart from continuously show itself. It wont exit or move on to the next function
Sorry if this is a bit silly but I don't really know what to do or how to describe the problem

```
    def main_menu():          
    menu_choice = input("""
---------------------------------------
Welcome to the GCSE Celebrity Dogs Game
 Please choose an option from the menu
---------------------------------------
1) Play the game
2) Quit
""")
    if menu_choice == 1:
     deck_choice()
    elif menu_choice == 2:
     print("Exiting game.....")
     quit()
    else:
     main_menu()


correct_numbers = [6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]


def deck_choice():
    num_cards = input("""
How many cards owuld you liek to play with?
**Please note this must be a number between 4 and 30 and cannot be odd**
""")
    if num_cards not in correct_numbers:
        print("Sorry, that number isnt valid. Please enter another number")
    else:
        return num_cards


main_menu()
```

Comment: Your indentation makes little sense. This isn't valid Python. Paste your code exactly as it is, select it, and then use the code button in the question editor to format it properly. This is especially important in Python with its significant white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either cast the `menu_choice` to `int` so you can compare it with an `int` or cast the int to a string in the `if` statement.

For example, to cast the input to an int:

```
menu_choice = input("""your menu""")

if int(menu_choice) == 1:
    # do stuff
```

Alternatively, cast int to string:

```
menu_choice = input("""your menu""")

if menu_choice == str(1):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: To make it a little clearer for OP. Input creates a `string` by default, you need to explicitly define it as a `int` to be able to compare it to another `int`.

Comment: I'm aware of using int for numbers but when i do this the program then throws up an error for the colon at then end of the "if menu_choice = 1:"

Comment: @L3Cache updated answer for a better explanation

Comment: Thanks, thats fixed it right up. :)